# Django,self.context['request']

Tags: django

I am studying JWT authentication.This example is not clear to me.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, user_logged_in

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import JSONWebTokenSerializer, jwt_payload_handler, jwt_encode_handler

class JWTSerializer(JSONWebTokenSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        credentials = {
            self.username_field: attrs.get(self.username_field),
            'password': attrs.get('password')
        }

        if all(credentials.values()):
            user = authenticate(request=self.context['request'], **credentials)
```

Where does
`self.context['request']` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During initialization you can pass to serializer extra context. Check this part of the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) for details.

DRF's generic views by default passing with additional context `request` object([source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L132)), which you can get inside serializer class with following syntax:

```
self.context['request']
```

Comment: Thnks,But, {'request': request} is something like key:value structure?

Comment: @MikiBelavista yes, it's dictionary. Since context is dict, to get `request` you should use `request` key: `self.context['request']`.